# Using nested loops to make a plot in Python

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7

I am trying to make a plot using Python with matplotlib. I have a function `streaks()` that takes a list of `n` booleans with probability `p` of getting 'True', and returns a list of succession streaks. For example, `[True, False, True, True, False]` yields `[1, 1, 2, 1]`.

I need to use this function 500 times for each value of n (from 0 to 400 in increments of 10). In each of these 500 trials for each value of n, I need to find the maximum succession streak and then take the average for the 500 trials.

The final plot that I should have, then, has an x-axis representing `n`, and a y-axis representing the average maximum streak.

For some reason, my code is not doing what I want and I feel like I have all the components. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
def averagemaximums():
    maxvals = []
    avgmaxvals = []

    for j in range(500):
        for n in range(0, 400, 10):
            maxvals.append(max(streaks(0.5, n)))
            a = (sum(maxvals))/(500)
            avgmaxvals.append(a)

    plot(avgmaxvals)
    show()
```

EDIT: Extra info as requested:

```
#Makes list of bools
def bools(p, n):
    return (rand(n) < p)

#Makes list that counts successive values
def streaks(p, n):
    run = bools(p, n)

    successionlist = []

    counter = 1
    for j in range(1, n):
        if run[j] == run[j - 1]:
            counter = counter + 1
        else:
            successionlist.append(counter)
            counter = 1
    successionlist.append(counter)
    return successionlist
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In less words, post code we can run (add `streaks(...)` definition), so it's easier for us to help you.

Comment: @Christian Sorry, I've edited the question. Hopefully it's clear enough now.

Comment: @Christian I edited it again. I had forgotten the last two lines. I'm not getting any errors. Just an incorrect plot.

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving the values of n that are used to create each value of a. Thus when you plot argmaxvals, you are plotting them against their list index instead of n.

Try this modification:

```
for j in range(500):
        for n in range(0, 400, 10):
            maxvals.append(max(streaks(0.5, n)))
            a = (sum(maxvals))/(500)
            avgmaxvals.append((n,a))
    x,y = zip(*argmaxvals)
    plot(x,y)
    show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your code fix doesn't seem to be fixing the problem, but I see the problem now and will try to find a solution.